# Wrong exponential using numpy?

Tags: calculus, numerical-calculus

The exponential $e^{-5^2/8}$ is supposed to give $0.04393693362$ but when using the following numpy code:
`print(np.exp((-5*5)/2*4.0))`, I get "1.9287498479639178e-22". Can you figure out what is wrong? I have stared at this for an hour now :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to place brackets around `2*4.0`. It's calculating $e^{-50}$ instead of $e^{-3.125}$.

Comment: Thanks. Much love